# Actualizar Usuario Model

Tags: django

Saludos estoy intentando actualizar el usuario de django desde un formulario html pero no me acepta la actualizacion este es mi formulario:

```
       <form action="{% url 'seguridad:actualizar_usuario' %}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
       <input type="hidden" name="usuario_id" id="usuario_id">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="value_required">Usuario</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="usuario" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="value_required">Correo</label>
          <input type="text" name="emailuser" id="emailuser" class="form-control" placeholder="usuario" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="value_required">Clave</label>
          <input type="password" name="passworduser" id="passworduser" class="form-control" placeholder="Deje en blanco para mantener la clave anterior"> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="value_required">Perfil</label>
          <select name="perfiluser" id="perfiluser" class="form-control" required="">
            <option value="1">Administrador</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="value_required">Estado</label>
          <select name="stateuser" id="stateuser" class="form-control" required="">
            <option value="1">Activo</option>
            <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

**views**

```
def ActualizarUsuario(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        from django.contrib.auth.models import User

        usuario_id = request.POST.get('usuario_id')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        emailuser = request.POST.get('emailuser')
        perfiluser = request.POST.get('perfiluser')
        stateuser = request.POST.get('stateuser')

        if request.POST.get('passworduser'):
            passworduser = request.POST.get('passworduser')
            #actualiza con clave
            user = User.objects.get(pk=usuario_id)

            user.username=username,
            user.password=passworduser, 
            user.email=emailuser,
            user.is_superuser = perfiluser,
            user.is_active = stateuser

            user.save()
        else:
            #actualiza sin clave
            user=User.objects.get(pk=usuario_id)
            user.username=username,
            user.email=emailuser, 
            user.is_superuser = perfiluser,
            user.is_active = stateuser
            user.save()

        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Usuario Actualizado !!')

        return redirect('seguridad:administrar_usuarios')
```

Los datos del usuario coloco en el formulario obteniendolos desde Ajax el cual funciona bien, pero el problema surge al actualizar me aparece asi en mi tabla de usuarios:

[image: update user]
Quiza alguna idea o que estoy haciendo mal. gracias de antemano !!

Comment: Pienso que is_active o is_superuser son campos booleanos. ¿Porqué le pones esos valores ?

Comment: Has intentado ver cómo te lo nuestra en una página? Puede que sea una configuración de la BD el motivo que se vea así. En principio estás cogiendo bien los valores pero intenta cogerlos así `stateuser = request.POST.get('stateuser', '')`